# Change the value of resx resource of Web controls from DLL

Tags: c#, resx, webproject

I'm having a hard time on changing the resx value from a referenced .NET web control

This is my scenario.

I have a XXX web control from YYY Project, i have a label that is getting the value from a resource file UIControl.resx

I have also a ZZZ web project and referenced the YYY Project DLL and utilized the XXX web control. Now, i want my user to change the value of the label without compiling using the resx file but seems changes does not appearing to reflect on my ZZZ web project. I can do this on a resource on the same project but not reference. Is it posible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be good if you can post the code of the XXX web control. Specifically the definition of the label.